# PySpark computation of weekly occurrences

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to compute the weekly occurrences of a word. That is, whether each word is more frequent this week than the previous week. For that I am kind of stuck. I did the following:

```
m = sc.parallelize(["oded,12-12-2018", "oded,12-03-2018", "oded,12-12-2018", "oded,12-06-2018", "oded2,12-02-2018", "oded2,12-02-2018"])
        m = m.map(lambda line: line.split(','))
        weekly = m.map(lambda line: (line[0], (parse(line[1]).strftime("%V%y"))))
        s = sql.createDataFrame(daily)
        s.groupby("_1", "_2").count().sort("_2")
```

the result is:

```
+-----+----+-----+
|   _1|  _2|count|
+-----+----+-----+
|oded2|4818|    2|
| oded|4918|    2|
| oded|5018|    2|
+-----+----+-----+
```

How can I go and get oded: 0  = ( 2 - 2 ) and oded2: 2 = (2 - 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use lag window function to find value from previous week , after you count words peer week. For weeks that don't have previous value value for count will be zero or you can use na.drop() to remove that lines completely.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, col,coalesce
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().partitionBy("_1").orderBy(col("_2"))
s.select("*", lag("count").over(w).alias("prev_week")).na.fill(0).show()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!